# Add two different svg element in g element of svg using d3.js from a dataset

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I want to add one circle and one text element to every group element of the svg based on the dataset, similar to the below one.

```
var dataset=[1,4];
<g>
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
<text x="100" y="100" fill="white">Hello World</text>
</g>
<g>
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
<text x="100" y="100" fill="white">Hello World</text>
</g>
```

here below my working sample code.

```
var svgSelection2=d3.select("#div-svg2").append("svg")
.attr("width",900)
.attr("height",500)
.style("background-color","lightgreen");

var dataset=[1,4];
var group=svgSelection2.selectAll("g")
.data(dataset2)
.enter()
.append("g");

var circles=group.selectAll("circle")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("cx",function(d,i){ return d*100 ;})
.attr("cy",100)
.attr("r",function(d,i){ return d*20;})
.attr("fill","blue");


var textElement=group.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("x",function(d,i){return d*100;})
.attr("y",100)
.text("Hello World")
.attr("fill","white");
```

This code append two circles and two elements to every group element.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to enter the same dataset again, so you can do this

```
var svgSelection2=d3.select("#div-svg2").append("svg")
        .attr("width",900)
        .attr("height",500)
        .style("background-color","lightgreen");

var dataset=[1,4];
var group=svgSelection2.selectAll("g")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

var circles = group.append("circle")
        .attr("cx",function(d,i){ return d*100 ;})
        .attr("cy",100)
        .attr("r",function(d,i){ return d*20;})
        .attr("fill","blue");

var textElement=group.append("text")
        .attr("x",function(d,i){return d*100;})
        .attr("y",100)
        .text("Hello World")
        .attr("fill","white");
```